# AWS PHP SDK only for Cognito Service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have added the following dependencies to access AWS Cognito Service from PHP application

"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.154",

And I found that it downloaded more files which add up to 21 MB, this is consuming more space. Is there a smaller package available for AWS cognito Service?

Look forward to your answers.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an officially supported library by AWS then you will want to continue use the official SDK, this will cover all AWS services but as you've noticed also pull in its over dependencies.

If you do not want to use this you have a couple of approaches you could take.

The first choice is to use someone else's implementation, if you look on [packagist](https://packagist.org/?query=cognito) you should be able to find a number of libraries that have been provided. When using third party dependencies ensure that it is still being supported (things to look out for such as outstanding issues or no changes for a while in its revision history).

The second choice is to implement your own by implementing the [cognito API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-reference.html). This will be a lot of work to maintain and develop especially as functionality changes or is added.

Personally I would suggest sticking with the AWS SDK unless you're very tight on space. It is patched frequently with new features being added within days (normally hours) of any announcements which will enable you to use it.